# ASP 3.0 Declare ADO Constants w/out Including ADOVBS.inc

Tags: asp-classic

I've written a simple form handler script using ASP3.0/VBScript and would like to add the inputted data (via the web) to an Access database located on my server. I'm using the OLEDB method to connect like so:

```
Cst = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("DataBase.mdb")

Dim Conn
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Mode = 3

Conn.Open Cst

Blah Blah Blah...
```

I currently have a file named ADOVBS.inc included at the top but would like to ditch it because I feel it's inefficient and wasteful. I'd like to define the constants as I need them- but I don't know how. What ADO constants would I need to define and where? The book that I'm using basically says "forget about that- pound include those 400 or so boogers in there and don't ask stupid questions!"

Any specific examples/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

you have a couple of options to choose from.  You can reference the metadata library in your page ( or in your global.asa file )  with

```
<!--
   METADATA    
   TYPE="TypeLib"    
   NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library"    
   UUID="{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}"    
   VERSION="2.5"
-->
```

or

you can simply copy a few constants from the adovbs file into your page to cover your needs.  For example

```
Const adCmdText = 1      'Evaluate as a textual definition    
Const adCmdStoredProc = 4 'Evaluate as a stored procedure
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course that the answer is **"Forget about that- pound include those 400 or so boogers in there and don't ask stupid questions!"** :)

But since you insist:

The best way is to encapsulate all data access function in one .ASP
Let's call it `dbHelper.asp`

Then put all the DB functions in there, like:

```
''// run a query and returns a disconnected recordset
Function RunSQLReturnRS(sqlstmt, params())
    On Error Resume next

    ''//Create the ADO objects
    Dim rs , cmd
    Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

    ''// Init the ADO objects  & the stored proc parameters
    cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString()
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstmt
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

    collectParams cmd, params

    ''//Execute the query for readonly
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    If err.number > 0 then
        BuildErrorMessage()
        exit function
    end if

    ''//Disconnect the recordset
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    ''//Return the resultant recordset
    Set RunSQLReturnRS = rs

End Function
```

At that point, you know that all you ado constants are in this file and you can start replacing them as wished.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant list of constants can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190225142339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/ASPScripts/PrintPage.asp?REF=/webtech/faq/beginner/faq7.shtml

I'll copy it here as well:

```
'---- CursorTypeEnum Values ----
Const adOpenForwardOnly = 0
Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adOpenDynamic = 2
Const adOpenStatic = 3

'---- CursorOptionEnum Values ----
Const adHoldRecords = &H00000100
Const adMovePrevious = &H00000200
Const adAddNew = &H01000400
Const adDelete = &H01000800
Const adUpdate = &H01008000
Const adBookmark = &H00002000
Const adApproxPosition = &H00004000
Const adUpdateBatch = &H00010000
Const adResync = &H00020000
```

Should be enough for inserting/selecting/updating records in database.