# Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on a classic ASP web application In that I have a requirement of inserting 100 records (no. of records may change it depends on particular user selection). For this I am using parameterized query and prepared statement my code is as follows:

```
Set objComm2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objComm2.ActiveConnection=stConnect 
objComm2.Prepared=true
objComm2.CommanText="insert into trader(RegistrationID,SalesID) values (?,?)"
objComm2.Parameters.Append objComm2.CreateParameter("@RegistrationID", adInteger, adParamInput)
objComm2.Parameters.Append objComm2.CreateParameter("@SalesID", adInteger, adParamInput) 

while NOT objSel.EOF
  objComm2("RegistrationID") = Session("RegistrationID") 
  objComm2("SalesID") = objSel("SalesInventoryID")
  objComm2.Execute
  objSel.MoveNext
wend
```

Here `stConnect` contains connection variables defind in my project web config file, `objSel`(its a record set object) contains required data to supply for insert operation.

Now my problem is when I am running this code I am getting the following error in appending parameters to command object:

```
Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information
was provided.
```

I couldn't find any error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you didn't define the constants `adInteger` and `adParamInput`.

Evidence:

```
>> Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>> oCmd.CreateParameter "@RegistrationID", adInteger, adParamInput
>>
Error Number:       3001
Error Description:  Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one
another.
```

but:

```
>> Const adInteger          =          3
>> Const adParamInput       =          1
>> Set oCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
>> oCmd.CreateParameter "@RegistrationID", adInteger, adParamInput
>>
>> <-- no news are good news.
```

**Update wrt comment:**

VBScript knows nothing about ad*, xl*, or wd* constants. If you don't include a file like adovbs.inc or define them yourself (`Const adInteger = 3`, ...) - and don't use `Option Explicit` to catch such errors - they are just Empty.

Comment: Do i need to define adInteger and adParamInput ? According to my knowledge adInteger is dbType and adParamInput species parameter direction in this  case its a input

Comment: thanks for your help i got it know

Comment: @kaleshanagineni I wouldn't advise declaring these manually. [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) set this once in your `global.asa` file and your good to go for the rest of the web application. Haven't used `adovbs.inc` or `adovbs.asp` for years, it's just pointless. Using METADATA is far cleaner and less maintenance.

Comment: @kaleshanagineni [ASP 3.0 Declare ADO Constants w/out Including ADOVBS.inc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5145607/692942)

Comment: thanks a lot for everyone for your answers.