# Error in Parameterized Query using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-express

I am getting the following Error in this parameterized query using Classic ASP.

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

Error is coming on this line `cmd.CommandType = adCmdText`

```
Dim requestedID
requestedID = Request("ID")

Dim requestedName
requestedName = Request("Name")

''' Create a parameterized SQL query
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE (ID = ?) AND (Name= ?)"

''' Create a Command object
Dim cmd
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

''' Create parameter objects and add them to the command
Dim paramID, paramName 
Set paramID = cmd.CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput,  , requestedID)
Set paramName = cmd.CreateParameter("@Name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, requestedName)

''' Add parameters to the command.

cmd.Parameters.Append paramID
cmd.Parameters.Append paramName 

''' Execute the query
Dim rs
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Are you using OLE-DB, ODBC, or another ADO provider? (This is relevant because not all providers support named vs. positional parameters).

Comment: Have you imported the ADODB Named Constants or using ADOVBS.INC? - [ASP 3.0 Declare ADO Constants w/out Including ADOVBS.inc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5146495). Without either of these VBScript will not know what `adCmdText` is.

Comment: I am using sql express database. I have added windows ADO  file link in global.asa file.

Comment: @Babar what was the fix?

Comment: What did you do to fix that, and where was the error? This could help other readers.